# listing all deleted files for a user with dropbox api

Tags: angular, typescript, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm working on a project that automates workflow for a very large organization. I'm working on listing all deleted files, which works fine on smaller accounts, but having trouble when I attempt to list one of the accounts that has thousands of files.

```js
getTrash(cursor = null) {
    let path = '';
    let body = {};
    if(cursor === null) {
      body = {
        path: '',
        include_deleted: true,
        recursive: true,
        limit: 1000
      };
      path = 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder'
    } else {
      body = {
        cursor: cursor
      };
      path = 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder/continue'
    }
    this.http.post(path, body, this.getRequestOptions()).subscribe((response) => {
      const data = response.json();
      data.entries.forEach((file) => {
        if (file['.tag'] === 'deleted') {
          this._trash.push(file);
        }
      });

      if(data.has_more === true) {
        this.getTrash(data.cursor);
      } else {
        this.trashSubject.next(this._trash);
      }
    });
  }
```

The `list_folder` endpoint works as expected, but the `list_folder/continue` seems return files from all of the users. I would expect the cursor to include all of the relevant request info, since its the only parameter that you can pass to the endpoint. Has anyone done something like this with that dropbox api?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean when you say "`list_folder/continue` seems return files from all of the users"? The `/2/files/list_folder[/continue]` calls take a parameter that is specific to a particular user. These calls will return information about everything in that user's account, including anything they have access to via shared folders. E.g., even if the contents of those shared folders were created by other users. Is that what you're referring to? If so, that's the expected behavior, and it can't be disabled, so you'd need to filter those.

Comment: Ah ok @Greg, let me try that and I will confirm.